# How can I add the conditions $i j k \neq 0$ and GCD[i,j,k]==1 of this table?

Tags: table

I have a tabe.

```
list = Table[{(x - i)^2 + (y - j)^2 + (z - k)^2 == 100}, {i, -2, 2}, {j, -2, 1}, {k, -2, 1}]
```

How can I add the conditions $i j k \neq 0$ and GCD[i, j, k]==1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Table[If[GCD[i, j, k] == 1 && (i * j * k) != 0, 
 {(x - i)^2 + (y - j)^2 + (z - k)^2 == 100}, Nothing],
   {i, {-2, -1, 1, 2}}, {j, {-2, -1, 1}}, {k, {-2, -1, 1}}]
```

Comment: Why did you delete old code? Is it correct? If `{i, -10, 10}, {j, -10,10}`?

Comment: In the old code I wrote `{}` instead of `Nothing` and then, as the last operation,  I had to delete `{}` with `ReplaceAll[{} :> Nothing]`. This is redundant, because you can already use `Nothing` within the `If`-clause.